# Are there concurrency issues when incrementing in update statement

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

I would like to keep track of branches and how much money they are holding. I want to have a `Branches` table with a column called `Balance`. I will be maintaining a log of transactions performed by the branch.

I will have applications executing statements like this...

```
UPDATE Branches SET Balance = Balance + @Amount WHERE BranchID = @BranchID
```

Am I going to have a situation where `UserA` is incrementing the balance from 100 to 120 and `UserB` is incrementing the balance from 100 to 180 and thereby losing the change made by `UserA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Applies to **SQL Server** - but should be somewhat the same for other RDBMS as well]
The first user to start updating that row will **exclusively** lock the row - so no second user can start an update at the same time.

By the time the second user's transaction is allowed to run, the value will already be updated to 120, so the second update will go from 120 to 200.

Comment: ok, so if I understand you correctly the reading part of the update (getting the amount to update) is processed after the first lock is released?

Comment: @Sebas: the reading part is done under an `Update` lock, which prevents other update locks from being placed on that row - so yes, once the first update begins (with reading the value), all other updates will have to wait for the first update operation to complete (or be rolled back)

Answer (score 0):

A lock is aquired on a table whenever a `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statement is executed on that table. Due to this lock it is impossible to have such conflicts.

User 1 will update the value and after the transaction finishes, User 2 will be able to update the value as well.

RDBMSs respect [ACID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and in this way execution of different statements are separated. You should not worry about conflicts of this matter.

Comment: Isn't the lock just done on the row that is selected and not on the entire table?

Comment: If a transaction has started and has not finished, the table cannot be modified. See `CONSISTENCY` principle, one of the ACID rules.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, I'm sure innodb locks the row only when you update a given record

Comment: @Sebas possibly, I haven't used it.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: that's completely wrong. All modern DBMS only lock the rows that are updated - with some exceptions though: SQL Server's lock escalation, MySQL's gap locks and similar things.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I cannot contradict you, the OP has tagged SQL Server in his post, and that is what I was referring to.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: I was referring to your comment "*if a transaction has started ...  the table cannot be modified*", which is wrong.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "by another transaction, if the current has not finished" I meant to say..

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a problem with any SQL server, unless the table is corrupted somehow. What usually happens is that SQL server will lock the table for the update and then release for the next update. If the requests come in simultaneously, one will be executed before the other, but neither will be thrown away.

Comment: That's wrong. Modern DBMS don't lock the table when updating a single row.

Comment: Ok... Note that you say something else in the comment to Radu below (" All modern DBMS only lock the rows that are updated ").